# Docker Compose + Ubuntu:22.04-Unable To Create cgroup...Read-only file system

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cgroup, slurm

I'm playing around with Docker Desktop(4.16.3) and [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html).  When I run `slurmd`, I get an error with the following complaint:

```
common_cgroup_instantiate: unable to create cgroup '/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/slurm' : Read-only file system
unable to build slurm cgroup for ns freezer: Read-only file system
unable to create slurm freezer xcgroup
Couldn't load specified plugin name for proctrack/cgroup: Plugin init() callback failed
cannot create proctrack context for proctrack/cgroup
error: slurmd initialization failed
```

I've searched high and low for a solution but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer.

One solution involved using the following command `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` along with grub.  But grub doesn't exist in the base image and it seems to be warned against because it somehow interfaces with `systemd`

I've also tried the hamfisted approach of making the missing directory, and changing the permissions but I still get a read-only error:

```
RUN mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/slurm:
#0 mkdir: cannot create directory '/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/slurm': Read-only file system
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the volume `/sys/fs/cgroup` on your host to a container.

As shown below.

```
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup
```